# How to install pip for Python 3.9 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 comes with Python 3.8. **I cannot uninstall Python 3.8** but I need Python 3.9

I went ahead and installed Python 3.9  from:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

> sudo apt install python3.9

How do I install pip for python 3.9?

Installing pip using
`sudo apt-get install python3-pip` does not work for me as it installs pip for python 3.8

Installing pip using `python3.9 get-pip.py` gives an error:

```
~/python_tools$ python3.9 get-pip.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/python_tools/get-pip.py", line 23704, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/python_tools/get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "/home/ubuntu/python_tools/get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpkwyc8h7j/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpkwyc8h7j/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpkwyc8h7j/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpkwyc8h7j/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 18, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
```

Comment: I recommend checking Eric Platon's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68523326/435129 before jumping into curl

Comment: Duplicate is not applicable. This question is a lot more specific (two Python installations and specific OS). Cause and solution will differ from the duplicate target.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can install `pip` for python 3.9 the following way:

```bash
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.9 get-pip.py
```

It is important you use `python3.9` instead of just `python3`, to ensure `pip` is installed for python 3.9.

If you see any permissions errors, you may need to use

```bash
python3.9 get-pip.py --user
```

If you get an error like `No module named 'distutils.util'` when you run `python3.9 get-pip.py`, and you are on a Debian-based Linux distribution, run

```bash
sudo apt install python3.9-distutils
```

and then rerun your `get-pip.py` command. If you are not on a Debian-based distribution, use the equivalent command for your distribution's package manager.

These instructions are based in part on the [official installation instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) provided by the pip maintainers.

---

This portion of my answer is a bit out of the scope of the question, since the question is specifically for python 3.9. However, for anyone trying to install pip on python 3.6 or older, at the time of writing the file at https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py only supports python 3.7 or newer.

The workaround is to instead download from `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/<python version>/get-pip.py` instead. For example, if you want to install pip for python 3.6, then you can download from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py, and then follow all of the steps above as usual.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I get an error when I try get-pip.py
I added the error to the body of my question.

Comment: @Gilson I updated my answer to include a solution for that

Comment: thank you! I appreciate your help. It worked!

Comment: type "pip3.9 install" to use pip

Comment: pip3 install -t ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ selenium

Comment: With `sudo apt install python3.9-distutils` it installs `python3.8` on Ubuntu 20.04. I want only `python3.9`

Comment: on ubuntu18, seems `sudo apt install python3.9-distutils` will got `python3.9 -m pip` ready. without `get-pip.py`.

Comment: For anyone suggesting edits, please note that (as I point out in my answer) my answer is based in part on the [official instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) for installing pip provided by the pip maintainers. Edit suggestions to install pip using a package manager or other similar changes are against the intent of my answer. If you want to offer ways to install via package manager, please leave that as an answer of your own. Also, I left out `ensurepip` so that my answer would be simpler.

Comment: Do check `sudo apt-get install python3.9-venv` in Eric Platon's answer below - that approach saves you having to set PATHs etc for the new binaries `get-pip.py` installs, which I'd rather avoid as it saves manual steps and config clutter.

Comment: I just get two pages of stack traces.

Comment: Someone referred to here but working on Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6 installed. But get-pip.py now require Python's minimal version is 3.7:
```Python
min_version = (3, 7)
if this_python < min_version:
```

Comment: @Keelung, please see my updated answer. I give instructions that should work for Python 3.6.

Comment: python3.9 get-pip.py results in Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mrt/get-pip.py", line 32099, in <module>
    main()
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'

Answer (score 35):

An alternative that relies only on `deadsnakes/ppa` is to install `python3.9-venv`.

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3.9-venv
python3.9 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip --version
# pip 21.1.3 from /home/.../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Perhaps easier to keep coherent over time, but forcing into Virtualenv.

---

This method was born out a problem on Ubuntu 18. Other proposals in the thread aimed at OP's target (20.04) did not work. The install script from PyPa ends on Ubuntu 18 with:

```sh
python3.9 get-pip.py
# ...
# AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'
```

Comment: This answer needs to find its way to the top

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3.10-venv` is now more appropriate these days.

Comment: What is `python3.9 - m venv venv` doing. I read in `man` `-m module-name
              Searches sys.path for the named module and runs the corresponding  .py  file
              as  a  script. This terminates the option list (following options are passed
              as arguments to the module).`. So is it a prep for the following `source` to work?

Comment: @Timo Yes, that is to allow for the `source` command. The `venv` module call creates a `venv` directory (unfortunate use of the same name?) to contain the virtual development environment for this project. Under this directory, the tree contains the dependencies under `lib` and executable scripts under `bin` (among others). In particular `activate` and `deactivate` allow to set or unset the virtual environment in the current shell (so calling `pip` or `python` uses the `venv/bin` ones instead of whatever default is available.

Answer (score 14):

Pip is included by default in python 3.4 and later.

```
python3.9 -m pip --version
```

If, for some reason, pip is not installed, you can install it manually by using get-pip:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.9 get-pip.py
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 with python3.9 from `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` `pip` is not on board.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else is running into seemingly bizarre WSL2 behavior from their pips, TechDog's suggestion fixed my WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04. It was the update-alternatives line, exactly as TechDog posted, that did the trick!

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 1
```

Comment: Owl, check your Python version and path. Was it 3.10 or 3.9?

Comment: I fixed it, it was a really weird problem: the links pointed to 3.9 but python3 was 3.6. However after a reboot, python3 was correct. Very strange indeed.

Comment: I hate those bugs! Glad it worked out for you after all.

Comment: Running Ubuntu 20.04 in Windows 10 WSL2. Ran into this issue setting up my python dev environment. This resolved my issue of "pip --version" returning `pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)` -> to -> `pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)`

Answer (score 4):

If you're building a [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/) container, the following [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) installs Python 3.9 on Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS):

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN set -ex && \
    apt install -y \
        software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt install -y \
        python3.9 \
        python3.9-distutils \
        python3.9-venv && \
    python3.9 --version && \
    python3.9 -m ensurepip && \
    pip3.9 --version
ENTRYPOINT []
```

The `software-properties-common` package introduces `add-apt-repository`. Installing the `python3.9-distutils` and `python3.9-venv` allows `ensurepip` to be invoked directly.

Anyway, the [Python standard library is supposed to include ensurepip as of Python 3.5+](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ensurepip.html) but distro maintainers seem to separate the installer into smaller pieces.

Comment: exactly what I needed; didn't not that `python3.9-venv` must be installed too

Answer (score 3):

this is a weird one, but it's the easiest and it works:

```
export PYTHON_VERSION_SHORT=3.9
apt-get install -y python${PYTHON_VERSION_SHORT} python3-pip && \
ln -s -f /usr/bin/python${PYTHON_VERSION_SHORT} /usr/bin/python3 && \
ln -s -f /usr/bin/python${PYTHON_VERSION_SHORT} /usr/bin/python && \
ln -s -f /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
```

when you install `pip3`, it's (at the time of writing) installed for `python3.8`. but if you overwrite `/usr/bin/python3` to link to `python3.9`, `pip3` will then be interpreted using python3.9, and you'll have a working pip against `python3.9`

I've been using this for some two years without a problem, but fingers crossed because it's no good practice at all, it'll break if `python3-pip` and `python3.9` have compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the steps I used to install in UBUNTU 16.4., prefix SUDO if needed. I had some issues in using `python` in the command line so I have used `update-alternatives` to default python3.9 to `python` command, please change the version if needed.

```
apt update
apt install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
apt update
apt install python3.9
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 1
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.9 get-pip.py
```

Comment: You need to install another package before this works: install python3.9-distutils

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ python3.9 -m ensurepip
```

Comment: /usr/bin/python3.9: No module named ensurepip

Comment: I also get no module named ensurepip

Comment: Ubuntu/Debian ship a modified Python with pip, the venv module, and ensurepip separated out.

Comment: This also works with Ubuntu22.04. To be a little more complete you can do: ```python3.9 -m ensurepip --upgrade```