# Installing Python3.9 and pip in docker image (and not python 3.8)

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pip

I'm trying to build a docker image to run some tests, and I'm having trouble convincing ubuntu to install python 3.9 and pip, and NOT python3.8.

starting Docker unbuntu:latest, it's no problem to install python3.9, but there is no pip. Ok, I'll try doing what all the answers suggests:

`apt-get install python3-pip`

but this installs **all ** of python3.8, plus other junk. Now, it does work at this point, but it bugs me to have a completely unnecessary version of python in an image that I want to be as small as it can be.

No, uninstalling 3.8 afterwards doesn't work, it removes pip.

How can I get python3.9, with pip, and no python3.8?

I did see this: [How to install pip for Python 3.9 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644782/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-9-on-ubuntu-20-04)

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

And when you run the script, it complains about needing distutils. No problem:

`sudo apt-get install python3-distutils`

And what does python3-distutils depend on? Why, python3.8, of course!

Comment: Have you considered using one of the [`python` base images](https://hub.docker.com/_/python)? They are tailored to be used with Python projects. In most cases I personally use a `-alpine` image. It's not going to get much more simple and smaller.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ubuntu store system python package in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` and share it for all python3 versions.

Inside an ubuntu 20.04 container (`docker run -ti ubuntu:20.04`):

```sh
apt-get update
apt-get install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
# Install py39 from deadsnakes repository
apt-get install python3.9
# Install pip from standard ubuntu packages
apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then you can invoke pip with `python3.9 -m pip ...`, but be careful, everything with be installed in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`.

But if all you need is a dockerized version of python3.9, it would be better to use the [official python docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python), available with debian or alpine (very light) as a base. Both use a standard `lib/pythonx.y/site-packages`.

By default these images defines entrypoint to the python interpreter, but you can override why `bash` or `busybox sh` (alpine).

### Edit for debian

launchpad repositories are build on ubuntu distribution. Using on over distribution can lead in libraries incompatibilities.

In deadsnakes ubuntu/xenial repository, python3.9 requires `libssl1.0.0`, but debian/buster offer `libssl1.1`.

The easiest way to get python3.9 in debian / buster is to use the official image (`docker run -ti python:3.9-buster`). Otherwise, build it ...

Comment: tl;dr The PPA is needed because installing a new Python is going to use the Ubuntu bulit-in Python installation version

Comment: For anyone else, this didn't seem to work on a Debian-based (buster) docker image.

Comment: After command `add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` you need again run command: `apt-get update` (because this actualize versions at now moment)

Comment: `apt-get install python3-9` does not work on ubuntu:20.04 and `apt-get install python3-pip` will install the pip for python3.8

Comment: The command to install python is `apt-get install python3.9` with a `.`, not `apt-get install python3-9` with a `-`

Comment: For Ubuntu images, add two lines from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1098881/389423