# pip / pip3 not install packages to latest python version

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip

I have begun learning on Linux. I got a Raspberry Pi 4. I Was able to update python from 3.7 to 3.9.4 and make it the default but pip / pip 3 will not install packages to the 3.9 site-packages. I have tried to uninstall both but neither are working.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: So you have two installations? Point to the pip executable in the right version.

Comment: Check this answer it might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644782/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-9-on-ubuntu-20-04