# Can't install pip with get-pip, zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pip, zlib

I'm trying to install fastapi on my ubuntu machine (20.04)
This PC has Python 2, Python3 (pointing to Python3.8) and Python3.9 installed.

If I try a pip3 install, it installs under Python3.8
I've seen a trick, using `python3.9 -m pip3 ...` but Python3.9 doesn't have the module pip or pip3.

I tried to install this using the get-pip.py trick, but it says there is no zlib.
I then tried to install that using a few methods, the `sudo apt-get zlib1g-dev` method (which installs but doesn't fix the iussue) as well as one where you download zlib and ./configure and make it, which also appears to work but doesn't.

A lot of solutions suggest using yum, but there's no yum package - sudo apt-get install yum doesn't work, and it's not on the ubuntu package manager site.

I tried many things, but nothing worked so far.

Either I need to get zlib to work, or I need to get the existing pip packaged to point to 3.9
I suppose I could just use venvs (which *is* installed for 3.9, somehow, even though pip isn't! ) or I could just use 3.8 instead, but these are both workarounds.

What do, Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

You should manually get the `get-pip.py` script.

```sh
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.9 get-pip.py
```

(Found this on [How to install pip for Python 3.9 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644782/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-9-on-ubuntu-20-04))

EDIT: `venv` is also installed with `apt install python3-venv` so it already could be without `pip`

Comment: I pasted that command in, but I get the same zlib not available response