# wsl ubuntu 20.04 -> with python3.9 and without python3.8

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04, distutils, wsl-2

Want to use **python3.9** with actual `pip` and `venv`. And remove *python3.8*.
I've installed **python3.9** like [that](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-9-on-ubuntu-20-04/). Then [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65644846/8571705). And `python3.9-venv` using `apt`.

Problem is `pip` and `venv` use `distutils`. Whish downloads via `python3-distutils` (`python3.9-distutils` is virtual package which refers to `python3-distutils`) and drags *python3.8* with it.

I tried to remove *python3.8* with all [that](https://gist.github.com/zhensongren/811dcf2471f663ed3148a272f1faa957) methods one by one. But each time `distutils` removes along with *python3.8*. I read [that](https://github.com/deadsnakes/issues/issues/150) dialogue. And I'm not quite sure but it seems there is no `distutils` outside of *python3.8* package.

So am I nailed forever with python3.8 or there is solution to remove it safely? Or somehow extract `distutils` and tie it with **python3.9**?

Answer (score 2):

### Do not remove the system Python

The Ubuntu 20.04 system needs Python 3.8 for its own functionality. The system Python, in this case Python 3.8, should not be removed, because that can make the system instable.

Python 3.8 does not need to be removed to use Python 3.9.

More info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652299/changing-pythons-default-version-breaks-ubuntu-20-04

### No need for `python3.9-distutils`

`python3-distutils` works for both Python 3.8 and Python 3.9, no need for `python3.9-distutils`.

Source: https://github.com/deadsnakes/issues/issues/150#issuecomment-761180428

### Create a venv virtual environment with Python 3.9

```
yourname@machine:~$ python3.9 -m venv /home/yourname/.venvs/my-venv-name
```

Activate the virtual environment:

```
yourname@machine:~$ source /home/yourname/.venvs/my-venv-name/bin/activate
```

Check the python version, it should be 3.9:

```
(my-venv-name) yourname@machine:~$ python -V
Python 3.9.9
```

Check the pip version within the venv, it is probably different than the system pip version:

```
(my-venv-name) yourname@machine:~$ pip3 --version
pip 21.2.4 from /home/yourname/.venvs/my-venv-name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Deactivate the virtual environment:

```
(my-venv-name) yourname@machine:~$ deactivate
```

Check the system pip version, outside any venv:

```
yourname@machine:~$ pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

---

Comment: I already installed newest ```pip``` to system level... Should I unistall it and reinstall python3.8 (which probably contains ```pip```)?
Also I dont have ```mkvirtualenv``` "command not found". Same as ```virtualenv```. I still able to proceed with ```python -m venv venv``` (python binded to python3.9).

Comment: Okay... I found the issue with manualy installed ```pip``` at system level. ```pip``` doesn't exist at ```/usr/bin```. It still able to install but to unistall some packages I need SU rights, but ```sudo pip uninstall ...``` leads to *"sudo: pip: command not found"*

Comment: Sorry about the `mkvirtualenv` and `virtualenv` commands. [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) is another package for creating virtual environments, instead of [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). `mkvirtualenv` is a command from [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a set of extensions for `virtualenv` to manage virtual environments created by `virtualenv`. Corrected my answer for use with `venv` (removed instructions for using `virtualenv` through `virtualenvwrapper`).